# Where does this vertical space come from?

Tags: spacing

I (thankfully) received couple of answers to one of my previous questions and while testing each one out I noticed a behavior to which I found no solution.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true, tracking=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe, paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
\pagestyle{empty}

%Needed for bridge related tabular enviroments defined below
\usepackage{array}

\raggedbottom

%********************************************************************************
%Use MnSymbol suit symbols
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolCards}{}

\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC5
   <6-7>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC6
   <7-8>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC7
   <8-9>  s*[1.2] MnSymbolC8
   <9-10> s*[1.2] MnSymbolC9
  <10-12> s*[1.2] MnSymbolC10
  <12->   s*[1.2] MnSymbolC12}{}

\newcommand{\mndiamond}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A2}}}
\newcommand{\mnheart}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A3}}}
\newcommand{\mnspade}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A4}}}
\newcommand{\mnclub}{{\usefont{U}{MnSymbolCards}{m}{n}\symbol{"A5}}}

\renewcommand{\c}{\mnclub}
\renewcommand{\d}{\mndiamond}
\newcommand{\h}{\mnheart}
\newcommand{\s}{\mnspade}
%********************************************************************************

\def\hand#1#2#3#4#5{\vtop{
   \hbox{\textls[100]{\textsc{#1}}}
   \handA \s{#2}
   \handA \h{#3}
   \handA \d{#4}
   \handA \c{#5}
}}
\def\handA#1#2{\hbox{\hbox to1em{\hss#1\hss}\handB#2\relax}}
\def\handB#1{\ifx#1\relax\else #1\if1#1\else\kern2pt \fi\expandafter\handB\fi}

\newcommand{\bd}[4]{
\begin{tabular}[b]{ m{6em} m{6em} m{6em}}
 & #1 & \\
#2 &  & #3\\
   & #4 &
\end{tabular}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent $1$THEIR UNTO THEM PLACE CANNOT SIGNS DARKNESS.

\bd
{\hand{NORTH}{J652}{AQJ972}{J}{103}}
{\hand{WEST}{10}{K83}{Q973}{AQJ92}}
{\hand{EAST}{KQ974}{10543}{652}{5}}
{\hand{SOUTH}{A83}{\textemdash}{AK1084}{K8764}}

\noindent THEIR UNTO TAKQJAKQJAQKHJ AKQJAKQJAQKHJ ARKNESS.

\hand{NORTH}{J652}{AQJ972}{J}{103}

THEIR UNTO THEM AKQJAKQJAQKHJ DARKNESS.

\bd
{North}
{West}
{East}
{South}

THEIR UNTO THEM PLACE CANNOT SIGNS DARKNESS.
\end{document}
```

This my pdfLaTeX output:

[image]

I am primarily concerned about the vertical space between region 1 and the following paragraph. The vertical space is not a byproduct of the macro,

```
\def\hand#1#2#3#4#5{\vtop{
   \hbox{\textls[100]{\textsc{#1}}}
   \handA \s{#2}
   \handA \h{#3}
   \handA \d{#4}
   \handA \c{#5}
}}
\def\handA#1#2{\hbox{\hbox to1em{\hss#1\hss}\handB#2\relax}}
\def\handB#1{\ifx#1\relax\else #1\if1#1\else\kern2pt \fi\expandafter\handB\fi}
```

because in region two the same macro produces no top or bottom vertical space.

Also, I suppose it is not a byproduct of the macro:

```
\newcommand{\bd}[4]{
\begin{tabular}[b]{ m{6em} m{6em} m{6em}}
 & #1 & \\
#2 &  & #3\\
   & #4 &
\end{tabular}
}
```

Because the same macro (essential a tabular environment) did not produce the same vertical space in region 3.

My question: What produces the vertical bottom spacing in region 1?

Also, there are some minor spacing problems in the output; is it possible to ask the LaTeX engine **not** to try to be smart and arrange (add or subtract) any kind of vertical spacing whatsoever?

Answer (score 6):

This space comes from using `\vtop` without realizing that `\leavevmode` should precede it.

When `tabular` processes a `p` cell (or `m` or `b`), it ensures the first line and last line in it have a strut; but this can only be done when the paragraph in the cell has started and `\vtop` doesn't do it. So you have the box, still in vertical mode, and then the final strut coinciding with the initial one.

Solution: if you really need to use `\vtop` (you don't for that job), be sure to have `\leavevmode` in front of it.

Here's the result if I change `\vtop` to `\leavevmode\vtop` in the definition of `\hand`:

[image]

Now you clearly see why you don't want `\vtop`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there an explanation for the vertical (tiny) spacing between the diagram in region 2 and the paragraph above it? (There is no vertical spacing with the diagram in region 1 and text above it.)

Comment: @blackened There is, with my correction. I'm not sure you want your hands to be displayed without some white space before and after them.

Comment: Sure I *do* want vertical spaces; the point is, I would like to control any kind of spacing whenever possible.

Comment: @blackened You can do it, provided you know what you're dealing with. There's interline space to consider, but also the fact that `tabular` inserts struts.

Comment: If I am not dealing with something “big”, where can I find information on this topic?

Comment: This is very bad approach to add `\leavevmode` in the macro which generates box. Then usage of such macro leaves vertical mode and inserts `\parindent `. Both is strictly undesirable in normal situations.

Comment: @wipet It's what *all* box making macros of LaTeX do. So what users expect from boxes. Consistency is the key, which of course doesn't prohibit to use `\hbox` or `\vbox` without `\leavevmode` in macros, provided these macro don't break the normal conventions at point of use.

Comment: You write: LaTeX hides normal behaviour of boxes from users. And users are confused (like here). This is very bad concept to hide TeX primitive behaviour.. That is all.

Comment: @wipet Where did I write that?

Comment: For example, there is `\parindent` before "WEST hand" in this example because of hidden `\leavevmode` in `tabular`. IMHO this is not what user wanted. And he can ask in future: why there is this space? The answer: bad LaTeX concept.

Comment: @wipet I bet the user doesn't expect that `\hand{...}\quad\hand{...}` typesets two lines. Should we ask?

Comment: @egreg When you write `\hand{...}<newline>\quad\hand{...}` in source file, I bet that users expect two lines in the output. And if they will be wrong then the reason is: LaTeX hides the true about boxes.

Answer (score 2):

The space isn't byproduct of my macro, of course. But my macro `\hand` produces box. The tabular item starts in vertical mode, places this box and finally it starts horizontal mode (I don't know why). This horizontal mode puts empty line after `#4` parameter in `tabular` environment.

You can type `\noindent#4` and, of course, `\noindent#3`, `\noindent#2` and `\noindent#1` in the `tabular` environment (macro `\bd`).

**Edit** Now, I do know why the horizontal mode is started at the end of the `tabular` item. The `\@finalstrut` is expanded here for putting strut at the end of the item. I did look into `latex.ltx` but this was not good idea. The macro is programmed as something obscure:

```
\def\@finalstrut#1{%
  \unskip\ifhmode\nobreak\fi\vrule\@width\z@\@height\z@\@depth\dp#1}
```

Why there is `\nobreak` immediately before `\vrule`? This is strange. Why only in horizontal mode the penalty is applied? And if horizontal mode isn't in current then it is started due to `\vrule`. It is better to not look into `latex.ltx` file (for keeping good state of mind).

**Edit2** I suggest to replace the `\bd` macro implemented by `tabular` to another macro which manipulates only with boxes. Then the `\leavevmode` nor `\noindent` is not needed:

```
\def\bd#1#2#3#4{\vbox{
  \bx{}{#1}{}
  \bx{#2}{}{#3}
  \bx{}{#4}{}
}}
\def\bx#1#2#3{\hbox{\rlap{#1}\kern8em\rlap{#2}\kern8em\rlap{#3}\kern6em}}
```

Comment: Contrary to what you claim, the space *is* a byproduct of your macros.

Comment: @egreg No. My macros creates box. If it is used in the environment where starting to horizontal mode is processed at the end of this environment then this is problem of this environment, no the mentioned box. Please, don't blame. If you put a boxed image (for example) in such environment then the same problem occurs. BTW: note that user accepted your `\ExplSyntaxOn` solution but he used mine solution.

Comment: @wipet Your macro behaves differently in vertical and horizontal mode, which is a “don't do it” in LaTeX. Since LaTeX is assumed in the question, you should add `\leavevmode` in front of `\vtop`. That's all.

Comment: `\includegraphics` generates box. `\framebox` generates box. It is normal that user needs sometimes box, not starting paragraph (which creates new box with `\hsize` width, what isn't always desired).

Comment: @wipet Woah! Guys, chill. It is not worth breaking each other over a question. I am thankful to both of you.

Also, I specifically mentioned that I am **testing** various approaches. The above problem is **not** necessarily specific to your macro—I have similar other vertical spacing problems, and I am simply trying to understand the underlying issue(s).

StackExchange should perhaps come up with another solution—when there are multiple answers, and the OP chooses one as the “accepted” answer, it sometimes creates unintentional situations.